# Azure DevOps Test Plan Cost

Tags: azure-devops

can anyone confirm that Test Plan as a Icon and function in AZURE is always available regardless of any subscription level , according to the price calculator in this link..
The pricing calculator 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/calculator/?service=azure-devops
mentions that the “Test Plans” Extension has a cost of ~70 AUD per user. 
Is this for Test Plan or Test Manager ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, test plan icon will be available if your user include one of license (Test plans, Visual Studio Enterprise, Test Professional, MSDN). This icon contains features for plan and  run test cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help !!